# Get ToString-expression from compiled class using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, intermediate-language

I have a class such as:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public override string ToString() => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
}
```

and I would like to be able to extract the ToString-expression in runtime using reflection like so:

```
var exp = typeof(Person).GetMethod("ToString").GetMethodBodyAsString();
```

where exp would be something like this: "${LastName}, {FirstName}" or at least enough to make it possible to reconstruct the expression with some more effort..

Is it possible to extract this from the IL-code returned by reflection on the method-body?

Comment: The C# code is compiled to IL. You could get the IL from the com piled assembly but I don't know if that will solve the issue you're looking at. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please read https://xyproblem.info/ and respond.  If you really need the capability of getting to that format string, the easiest way to do it is to declare a  property containing that string, and then use that string in a `string.Format()` call for your `ToString()` method.